# How to get corresponding character value by sending 4 digits in php

Tags: php

I want to get corresponding character value by sending 4 digits.

```
0001 = AAAA
0002 = AAAB
0003 = AAAC
0004 = AAAD
...
0035 = AABC
```

For example in php code I will pass 0001 to function it will return AAAA

0002 it will return AAAB.

How can I achieve this type of hashing in php ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I stuck in logic of how to get that

Comment: okay; Then just start with pasting the ground structure of your function. We will give you some hints and advice. Hints: 1. your function takes 1 parameter as string 2. split your string into an array 3. go trough each character of the array covert it what you want 4. return it

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

Here I split the string into an array with [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php). After this I loop through each element of the array with a foreach loop. The if statement is there to change all 0's -> 1's , since 0 and 1 should output A from your expected output.

Then I convert the digits to characters with [`chr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) (That now 1 -> A I add 64 to every digit. Why? Because this is the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value of the character)

```
<?php

    function convert($number) {
        $str = "";
        $digits = str_split($number);
        foreach($digits as $digit) {
            if($digit == 0) $digit++;
            $str .= chr($digit+64);
        }
        return $str;
    }

    echo convert("0002");

?>
```

Output:

```
AAAB
```

Comment: thanks Rizier123 for valuable comment but above script gives wrong answer from 0010  .. so on  for 0010 it gives AAAA instead of AAAJ.

Comment: @Awesome123 What is the pattern of this?

Comment: 0001 = AAAA
0002 = AAAB
0003 = AAAC
0004 = AAAD
0005 = AAAE
0006 = AAAF
0007 = AAAG
0008 = AAAH
0009 = AAAI
0010 = AAAJ
0011 = AAAK
0012 = AAAL
0013 = AAAM
0014 = AAAN
0015 = AAAO
0016 = AAAP
0017 = AAAQ
0018 = AAaR
0019 = AAAS
0020 = AAAT
0021 = AAAU
0022 = AAAV
0023 = AAAW
0024 = AAAX
0025 = AAAY
0026 = AAAZ
0027 = AABA
0028 = AABB
0029 = AABC
0030 = AABD

Comment: @Awesome123 But the output is always 4 characters?

Comment: @Awesome123 This doesn't makes any sense at all! In your question: 0035 -> AABC and now here 0029 -> AABC ?!

Comment: Yes..I have given an example as 0035 -> AABC..but it should work correctly as 00029->AABC

Comment: Does not matter if output is always 4 characters